# According to Biblical Unitarians, is it theoretically possible for God to incarnate as a human and live a holy and humble life?

Tags: nature-of-god, free-will, incarnation, omnipotence, unitarianism

For Biblical Unitarians, and from a theoretical standpoint, can God make use of His omnipotence and free will to take on human form and teach us by way of example what it is to live a holy and humble life, from birth to death? According to Biblical Unitarians, is this something possible for God, or is it beyond His capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is there is no single answer on this for all Biblical Unitarians, but given what I understand of Biblical Unitarianism, the answer is probably:

No. "God is Spirit." (John 4:24) 'Omnipotence' is a word with a classical theological development that isn't found in the Bible, although the word 'pantokrator' which means 'all-ruling' or 'all-mighty' is. God is the Creator (Genesis 1:1). As such, He could create a human who in turn could teach us by way of example what it is to live a holy and humble life - and that is exactly what He did.

> "[The incarnation] appears to mean that the divine Maker became one of
> His own creatures, which is a prima facie **contradiction** in
> theological terms. [...] Such an assertion, considered abstractly
> against the background of Old Testament monotheism, might seem
> blasphemous or nonsensical— as indeed, orthodox Judaism has always
> held it to be." [Jesus Christ: Incarnated or Created?](https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/articles/jesus-christ-incarnated-or-created)

and

> "Jesus makes clear reference to two distinct categories in John 3:6
> when he says that the “Flesh gives birth to flesh, but the Spirit
> gives birth to spirit.” Jesus clearly declared God to be “spirit”
> (John 4:24). Note that he did not say, “I am spirit,” or “God is
> flesh” or even “The Father is spirit.” By thus placing “God” in the
> category of “spirit,” when he himself is clearly a man of flesh and
> blood, Jesus effectively excluded any possibility that he was God. If
> God, being spirit, can incarnate Himself as a man, then the clear
> scriptural distinction between flesh and spirit disintegrates. But God
> the Creator, who is spirit, can create flesh, as He did in Genesis 1."

Furthermore

> Athanasius [a bishop of Alexandria who spearheaded what became the
> orthodox Trinitarian position] says that God can do anything He
> chooses to do, and that He chose to turn Himself into a man for the
> sake of our salvation. Jesus Christ is not one of God’s creatures, he
> insists, but God Himself, incarnated in human form. These sound like
> clear statements, but, actually, they are hopelessly confused.
>
> Can God do anything He chooses to do? Of course—except those things
> that are inconsistent with being God. Can He choose to be evil or
> ignorant? Could He be the Devil—or nothing at all?
>
> Perfection cannot be improved upon or changed. He is not a pantheistic
> “god” who dwells in everything. He is holy, meaning that He stands
> apart from and above His creation, yet is intimately involved with it.
> Therefore, God cannot alter His essential nature, which by definition
> is perfect, and perfection cannot be improved upon. But even if He
> could, in doing so He would, by definition, no longer be “God.”

To think God Himself could incarnate is to get caught up in a *category error*. It is like asking "Could God not be loving?" God *is* love (1 John 4:8). Or "Could God be unjust?" A core attribute of God is justice. 'Omnipotence' does not mean God can defy his own nature.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120380/discussion-on-answer-by-anthony-burg-according-to-biblical-unitarians-is-it-the).